# Material-ui calendar crashed while reloading the page on device toggle bar

Tags: css, reactjs, responsive-design, material-ui, next.js

Calendar renders correctly on the page but problem arises when I am  try to simulate for android devices (on browser dev tools -->  device toggle bar).
I wonder why calendar crashed on android devices while reloading page but except for  iOS devices.

Accordion action for picking date

```js
<AccordionActions
    sx={{
        width: "100%",
        height: "100%",
        backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF",
        // boxShadow: "0px 2px 23px 0 #EDEDED",
        borderRadius: "6px",
    }}
>
    {//#Material UI <Box/>}
    <Box
        sx={{
            width: "100%",
            height: "100%",
            backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF",
            // boxShadow: "0px 2px 23px 0 #EDEDED",
            // borderRadius: "6px",
        }}
    >
        <ResponsiveDatePicker />
    </Box>
    <Box
        ...
    </Box>
</AccordionActions>
```

Date picker component with Localization provider from `@mui/lab/AdapterDateFns'.

```js
<LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
    {//#Calendar from MUI}
    <CalendarPicker
        minDate={new Date()}
        date={date} onChange={(newDate) => setDate(newDate)}
    />       
</LocalizationProvider>
```

Crashed calendar:

[image]

Comment: if you can put your log ?

Comment: There is no error log related to this rendering. Date picker renders correctly on the page. Only it is crashes while simulating it  on device toggle bar with android devices.